# Is there a way remove property using Data Annotation in Asp.net MVC3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, data-annotations

```
Public class UserMetdata
  {
    [Required]
    [Display(Name="User ID")]
    public int UserID { get; set; }

    [Display(Name="User Name")]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

}
```

I dont want to UserName to be shown in View. Its similar like creating not required Annotation. One solution is by **deleting UserName form Class but i dont want that**.
How can it be done using Data Annotation.

Comment: Please show us the code for your view.

Comment: Its normally like we use in view through model. The only thing i have to do is not allowing that property to come in view.

Comment: I mean can we have a [NotRequired] attribute like [Required] which would totally not show that attribute in view

Comment: Do you have a requirement to create views on-the-fly or could you just omit the field from the generated code?

Answer (score 4):

You could use [ScaffoldColumnAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.scaffoldcolumnattribute.aspx) for that property

```
[ScaffoldColumn(false)]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

This will work **only** when you let framework dynamically generate your views by calling `@Html.DisplayForModel()` or like, and you **DO NOT** have defined display template for that model at `Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates` or `Views/ControllerName/DisplayTemplates`. Otherwise, you should edit that display template and remove corresponding line from it

Comment: No but that property is still available in view. But that shouldnt be

Comment: This attribute can be seen in action when you let framework dynamically create your views in runtime. Did you define static DisplayTemplate for that class?

Comment: No its normal class with property

Comment: This definitely works - @Padmalochan, you should check your code. And down-voter, I would be thankful if you could comment your action

Comment: @Html.EditorFor(model => model.UserName ).. I dont want UserName to come into this page

Comment: @Padmalochan you instruct framework to generate UserName editor, and it does that. Now I really don't undersand what are you trying to achieve

Comment: Private int UserID { get; set; }.Now this property cannot be accessed in a view. Can we do same this by declaring it private and providing some custom Data Annotation